# Delphi ChangeServiceConfig2 error setting delayed start

Tags: delphi, service

XE2 under Win7 64bit, code compiled for 32bit: I'm trying to set the delayed-start property on a service's config in the AfterInstall event.  QueryServiceConfig2 gets me the existing value just fine, but calls to ChangeServiceConfig2 return $57 (bad parameter) via GetLastError.  I'm using a var of the SERVICE_DELAYED_AUTO_START_INFO type as declared in WinSvc, but I've tried vars of various other storage sizes without success.  Calls to ChangeServiceConfig2 work OK when setting the service's description.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please show your actual `AfterInstall` code. Error $57 (`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`) means you are passing an invalid input parameter to `ChangeServiceConfig2()`.

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect us to explain why your use of `QueryServiceConfig2` is failing with a bad parameter error, when you don't show us the code where you're using the function. *Doctor, my foot looks funny. It's not quite the color it usually is, and it's not shaped quite right. I'm not going to give any more details, or let you see my foot. What's wrong, and how do I get better?*

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, and yeah, showing the code would have been better, but turns out that it might not have been that helpful.  I found today that the BOOL value passed in the info structure can only be set to a numeric value of 0 or 1 - any other value (specifically, the -1 used by Delphi for TRUE) raises the $57 bad-param error.  I found this because setting the param to FALSE did not generate the error but setting it to TRUE did.  Changing it to an integer and trying different values led me to the only two acceptable values.  This is inconsistent with every other Windows API call taking a BOOL param that I can think of, which is why it stumped me.  Anyway, thanks, guys.